# What should go in our main chat feeds?

Tags: discussion

Being newly created we have zero feeds appearing in our main chat right now. What blogs, news sites, or other important coffee related things should appear in our main chat room's feed? Post your suggestions/submissions.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added a feed for this site (meta.coffee) already, since meta's a very important part of the community.

Comment: @Doorknob add that as an answer so I can upvote (for the meta rep as much as that mattters lol)\

Answer (score 2):

We have a New Questions feed on another site that I frequent. It's a great way to make sure frequent chat users are reviewing all incoming questions. Being a brand new beta, it would also be a good place for some of the discussions that will happen around what is on/off topic.

```
http://coffee.stackexchange.com/feeds
```

Answer (score 1):

[Newest [coffee] questions on Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=coffee&sort=newest). Might be some good overlap if people putting coffee in ovens (or whatever it is they do over there) need advice.